# Can I variably choose what Vue.js component to use in a template?

Tags: vue.js, components

Let's say I have a list of objects, like this:

```
[
  {
    "component": "component-a",
    "data": { "x": 42 }
  },
  {
    "component": "component-b",
    "data": { "state": "New York" }
  }
]
```

I am looping through that list, like this:

```html
<div v-for="item in items">
  // ...
</div>
```

I want to choose what component to use based on `item.component` in each iteration.
Is there a way to get Vue.js to render the following?

```html
<div>
  <component-a data="{x:'a'}"></component-a>
</div>
<div>
  <component-b data="{state:'New York'}"></component-b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are looking for [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

```
<div v-for="item in items">
  <component v-bind:is="item.component" data="item.data"></component>
</div>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic component by using the `is` property in your html. The is property will require that you pass a string (the component name), and it will convert it to the real component.

```
<div v-for="item in items">
    <div v:is="item.component" :data="item.data"></div>
</div>
```

You should bind both `data` and `is` properties using the `:` prefix, because the variables must be passed to the component as variables, from the `item` object. If you don't use them they will be passed as strings (eg 'item.component') which is wrong.